# your binary is not optimized for iphone 5 for visual studio

Tags: xamarin, deployment, visual-studio-2017

I have an error when attempting to upload my ipa using the application loader. I am using visual studio 2017 on the latest xamarin build 4.5
I am using a LaunchScreen.storyboard. I also have the the iPhone 5 images in the asset catalog.
Anyone else having problems or could offer a solution?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.ExampleApp.ExampleOfApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </array>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
        <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Example App</string>
        <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
        <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
        <true/>
        <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>10.3</string>
      <key>UILaunchImages</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
          <string>7.0</string>
          <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
          <string>Default-568h.png</string>
          <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
          <string>Portrait</string>
          <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
          <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
      </array>
        <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
        <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>  
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: please search before posting - there are dozens of posts about this on SO already

Comment: I have. Tried all of them. In my case this is an issue with visual studio and the xamarin info property list.

Comment: To be more clear. Most of those answers were for xcode. This deployment is with visual studio. Specifically with the release of xamarin 4.5 to visual studio.

Comment: I have also posted this question on xamarin forums just for more coverage. It has a little bit more detail into my configuration. I will post the answer to this question here if it is answered there.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95617/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved on xamarin forums

Here is the link below to the answer on the forums

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95617/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5